# Spectral norm bound for lower triangular matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, spectral-graph-theory, permanent, spectral-radius

Let $A$ be a $0/1$ square matrix which can be permuted to a non singular or a singular lower triangular matrix. Determinant is either $0$ or $1$. Can we provide tighter upper bounds on its spectral norm better than the usual bounds?

Assume the matrix has no $2\times2$ bicliques.

Comment: Any matrix can be written as a sum of an upper and a lower triangular matrices. So, up to a factor $2$, there cannot be fundamentally better bounds for triangular matrices.

Comment: Saying that the determinant/permanent is $0$ or $1$ is not a very strong constraint on a triangular matrix ;).

Comment: Sure, by the argument in my first comment, $\geq n/2$ is possible (and is attained on the matrix with $1$ everywhere above the diagonal). Of course, now that the question has changed, my comments are less relevant.

Comment: If you post an answer I will accept with $n/2$ solution.